# SP2010 FullTetSqlQuery no results, worked on SP2007

Tags: sharepoint-2010, full-text-search

This code worked in our WCF service with SP 2007.  In our new server on SP2010 this doesn't work.  I do not know if the code needs to change or if there's something different about the configuration

Is this code wrong?  Are there other configuration things I need to do?  Search service is started.

```
StringBuilder queryText = new StringBuilder();
                queryText.Append("SELECT PreferredName ");
                queryText.Append("FROM SCOPE() ");
                queryText.Append("WHERE \"scope\" = 'People' ");

                Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.FullTextSqlQuery query = new Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.FullTextSqlQuery(SPContext.Current.Site);
                query.QueryText = queryText.ToString();
                query.ResultTypes = Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ResultType.RelevantResults;
                query.RowLimit = 50;

                Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ResultTableCollection results = query.Execute();
                if ((int)ResultType.RelevantResults != 0 && results.Exists(ResultType.RelevantResults))
                {
                    ResultTable tblResult = results[ResultType.RelevantResults];
                    DataTable relResultsTbl = new DataTable();
                    relResultsTbl.TableName = "Relevant Results";
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet("resultsset");
                    ds.Tables.Add(relResultsTbl);
                    ds.Load(tblResult, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, relResultsTbl);

                    foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        accountNamesFromSearch.Add(dataRow["AccountName"] as string);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: "Doesn't work"? What does it do? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Quickly See if you can get the desired result in this [MOSS Search tool](http://mosssearchcoder.codeplex.com/releases) good way to debug these kind of cases, rather than breaking our heads.